# PandasGUI ERROR — tornado.application — Exception in callback functools.partial

Tags: tornado

When I try to run a a jupyter notebook program with PandasGUI, I get: PandasGUI INFO — numexpr.utils — NumExpr defaulting to 4 threads.

That's followed by: PandasGUI ERROR — tornado.application — Exception in callback functools.partial(<function Kernel.enter_eventloop..advance_eventloop at 0x000002A7E8AAEDC8>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\david.faltenhine\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback
ret = callback()
File "C:\Users\david.faltenhine\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 314, in advance_eventloop
eventloop(self)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

If I continue and run: gui = show(df) PandasGUI loads my df but hangs.

I am able to load and run the titanic example data set, which seems to run fine, with no info message or errors...

Edit: I've tried trimming down the amount of code that I'm loading.  The info message has gone away but still getting the tornado\ioloop.py & ipykernel\kernelbase.py errors...

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a conflict between PandasGUI and matplotlib

Removing the following two statements eliminates the error and allows PandasGUI to run:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline